# Parsing a XML file and handling missing tags

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a XML file in order to retrieve the data in a list.

I need to extract the TITRE_N, the AUTEURS_N and the RESUME_N. I know how to do it but my problem is that for some reference, I don't have any data for AUTEURS_N. there is no tag and the result as you can think it that all the data after are shift! Do you know how I can parse this doc and handle the fact that sometimes I'm missing one tag that I usefully use?
thx a lot!

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far

Comment: thx. I tried this import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('TOUTMMMM.XML')
root = tree.getroot()
my_list_titre = []
my_list_auteur = []
my_list_resume = []


for TITRE_N in root.iter('TITRE_N'):
  my_list_titre.append(TITRE_N.text)
for AUTEURS_N in root.iter('AUTEURS_N'):
  my_list_auteur.append(AUTEURS_N.text)
  print(AUTEURS_N.text)
for RESUME_N in root.iter('RESUME_N'):
  my_list_resume.append(RESUME_N.text)
a = len(my_list_resume)
i = 0
print()
while i < a:
  print(my_list_titre[i])
  print(my_list_auteur[i])
  print(my_list_resume[i])
  print()
  i += 1